# Remove Subview using it's own button like UIAlertView

Tags: ios, iphone

I am working on a project where I click on 'Add Comment' button on main view and that load another XIB as a subview using following code. This XIB has cancel button just like UIAlertView. I want to dismiss this subview by clicking on Cancel Button but `[self.view removefromSuperview];` does not work!!!

```
AddCommentViewController *commentView = [[AddCommentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddCommentViewController" bundle:Nil];

commentView.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 80, 300, 285);

[self.view addSubview:commentView.view];
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[self.commentView removefromSuperview];`?

Comment: Problem is there is IBAction button on subview. I want to dismiss this subview using that IBAction button. It should be same as dismiss UIAlertview when pressed cancel button!! But [self.view removefromsuperview] code doesn't work.

Comment: Right I see, hmm I wonder if the reference to superView from the subview is the subview itself, not the actual superView.

Comment: I would probably make the subview a property and then do what I first suggested. That would be my approach.

Comment: Nope. I did make subview property and try to remove. But didn't work. Tries to hide either but didn't work too. Would like to look into my code? It will really appreciated!

Comment: Yes show how you call the cancel code.

Comment: Actually, try `[self removeSuperview];`

Comment: - (IBAction)cancelBtn:(id)sender In this method I am calling [self.view removefromSuperview]; but keep failing.

Comment: DO you think using appDelegate to remove view controller will work?

Comment: Can you provide email address so I can send you my code is possible? Or email to me: meet86@gmail.com and I can reply to you.

Comment: If `[self removeSuperview];` does not work, and setting it to a property and calling it on the property doesn't work, I don't know how to do it. I think we need someone with more experience.

Comment: @user2694792 check the sub-views of your superview if commentView is there in the list. You might have added it to some different view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from somewhere else, the fact that you instantiate commentView each time you press add comment. From the rootView's point of view, commentView is a local variable inside addComment button's action, and will be released just after you press add. You have to declare your commentView as a property and alloc/init it only once @viewDidLoad. Than you can add/remove it as many time you like, without calling alloc/init again. You just have to add some extra "clean" methods each time you add it.

Comment: Hey Calin, thanks you are right. I was alloc/init new view controller when button pressed. I declare new View Controller as  Property, alloc/init in view did load method. AND it's works fine.